# Mobile issue: when tapping randomly anywhere, I'm redirected to some random route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have completed my project written in Next.js 13.4.19. After I deployed it, some totally irrational things started to happen.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Visit https://programistapomyslow.pl in a **mobile browser**.
2. Start tapping somewhere (on headers, paragraphs, etc.) where links do not exist.
3. You will be redirected to some random route.
4. I attach a YouTube video as I'm unable to show it any other way.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/y7-80lTqGAc

On video, I tap on the `h1` heading (no links there). When I tap, Im navigated to some random routes?! Every time it can be a different route - it's a lottery.

I have no idea what's going on and it's hard for me to even find any reference point to debug.

Well, you could think that I just put random links all around - no I didn't. Please check the source code in a browser.

**It happens across the entire application on mobile. It all works normally in desktop browsers.**

Different phones & browsers have been checked: chrome, safari, mozilla | iphone 5s, iphone 6s, iphone 12 pro

Hmm, any idea?

Next.js version: 13.4.19

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@ingameltd/node-przelewy24": "^2.1.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.12",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.12",
    "@react-email/link": "0.0.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/node": "20.5.9",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "mongodb": "^6.1.0",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "@react-email/button": "0.0.10",
    "@react-email/column": "0.0.7",
    "@react-email/body": "0.0.2",
    "@react-email/container": "0.0.8",
    "@react-email/font": "0.0.1",
    "@react-email/head": "0.0.5",
    "@react-email/heading": "0.0.8",
    "@react-email/hr": "0.0.5",
    "@react-email/html": "0.0.4",
    "@react-email/img": "0.0.5",
    "@react-email/row": "0.0.5",
    "@react-email/section": "0.0.9",
    "@react-email/text": "0.0.5",
    "@react-email/render": "0.0.7",
    "react-email": "1.9.3-canary.0"
  }
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` in your `<nav>` element is "hanging" over your headline element and every time you tap the headline, you select one of the navbar menu links.

The navbar menu currently has a `opacity: 0`, which makes it transparent and therefore invisible, but it is still clickable.

You could try to add a `display: none;` to your css-class of the hidden navbar element and change it to `display: flex` (which is the current value), when you click the burger icon. Alternatively you could try `visibility: hidden`.